# pyqt5 how to code call the converted .py file rather than .ui file

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I have an application where I can create the layout in pyqt designer which will make a .ui file. I also have a gui script that when running uses this .ui file.

I have been able to convert the .ui file into a .py file however I would like to have my code call the converted .py file.

summary:

main.ui file which is generated from pyqt designer

main.py file which is generated from main.ui

gui.py which uses main.ui as shown in code snip below

how could I make gui.py use main.py and not main.ui?

```
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('main.ui', self)
```

Comment: Read the official PyQt guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generated code consists of helper class, just import it, instantiate and call `setupUi` in `__init__`

```
from main import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow)
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui = ui
```